# Using angular 4 with material slows down build process

Tags: angular, angular-material

Without using angular material webpack builds my app with aot in 30-40 seconds, but when I include material components to my app, build process becomes very slow and takes about 140-160 seconds, mostly being on `92% chunk asset optimization` step.

What could cause such problems and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you importing individual widget modules, instead of `MaterialModule`? By the way, what is your OS?

Comment: @torazaburo yes, I'm importing individual modules, such as MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule, same as in [guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started). I'm using windows 10.

Comment: You might want to experiment with using Linux; on Windows, you could use WSL. You're likely to get a speed-up in build times of 2-3x.